# Opensource nlp tools for subject/topic tagging

Tags: nlp, data-mining, bigdata, stanford-nlp

Which are good open source tools for subject tagging? I am getting post and comments for each post.

Categories of posts are: `Job, discussion, services, events, talent, buy/sell`

Some posts would have tags, I need to predict tags for other post. Algorithm should also be able to tag new coming posts.

Each `post` will have `comments`, The comments has to be `predicted` if it is on `topic/off-topic` or spam.

Tags can be like: `marketing, sell, suggestion, entrepreneurship etc`

There are few NLP tools and librarues  like `weka, rapidminer, nlptk, GATE, MOA, KEEL Miner`.

But i have not used and dont know which is most suitable.

Any help appreciated : )

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: MY customized algo is on different thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314817/proposed-nlp-algorithm-for-text-tagging

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the classifier inside LBJ for this: 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/LBJ

Here is a tutorial : 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/~mayhew2/lbjava_tutorial/